# How to fix Creative Tim material design dashboard charts incomplete display with material UI animations?(Grow, Slide etc_

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, transition

I'm having the following problem as shown in picture. The Component of creative tim's charts width and height is messed up. This is because of using Grow Transition of material UI. This is when first time component is loaded with transition

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl8y6.jpg)

When i re-click on same tab, It loads perfectly fine but there's no transition since component is already mounted as shown in the following picture

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/782Mc.png)

I've tried to use fixed width and height for the charts but no avail.

So how do i make work of this chart perfectly with material UI transitions(Grow,Slide) without loading problems?

#### PS: I'm designing my own Interface with animation and transitions based on creative tim theme and material UI. It's using multiple transitions on same page during load.

#### Code:

```
import React from "react";
// react plugin for creating charts
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";
// @material-ui/core
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
// @material-ui/icons
import Store from "@material-ui/icons/Store";
import Warning from "@material-ui/icons/Warning";
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import LocalOffer from "@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer";
import Update from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
import ArrowUpward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpward";
import AccessTime from "@material-ui/icons/AccessTime";
import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";
import BugReport from "@material-ui/icons/BugReport";
import Code from "@material-ui/icons/Code";
import Cloud from "@material-ui/icons/Cloud";
// core components
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.js";
import Tasks from "components/Tasks/Tasks.js";
import CustomTabs from "components/CustomTabs/CustomTabs.js";
import Danger from "components/Typography/Danger.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "components/Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";
import CardFooter from "components/Card/CardFooter.js";
import { bugs, website, server } from "variables/general.js";
import {
  dailySalesChart,
  emailsSubscriptionChart,
  completedTasksChart,
} from "variables/charts.js";
import { Grow } from "@material-ui/core";
import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function ProductsHome(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Grow in={true} timeout={1000}>
        <div>
          <GridContainer>

            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
                  <CardIcon color="warning">
                    <Icon>content_copy</Icon>
                  </CardIcon>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Used Space</p>
                  <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                    49/50 <small>GB</small>
                  </h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardFooter stats>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <Danger>
                      <Warning />
                    </Danger>
                    <a href="#pablo" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                      Get more space
                </a>
                  </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader color="success" stats icon>
                  <CardIcon color="success">
                    <Store />
                  </CardIcon>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Revenue</p>
                  <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>$34,245</h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardFooter stats>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <DateRange />
                Last 24 Hours
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                  <CardIcon color="danger">
                    <Icon>info_outline</Icon>
                  </CardIcon>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Fixed Issues</p>
                  <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>75</h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardFooter stats>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <LocalOffer />
                Tracked from Github
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                  <CardIcon color="info">
                    <Accessibility />
                  </CardIcon>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Followers</p>
                  <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>+245</h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardFooter stats>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <Update />
                Just Updated
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>
          <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
              <Card chart>
                <CardHeader color="success">
                  <ChartistGraph
                    className="ct-chart"
                    data={dailySalesChart.data}
                    type="Line"
                    options={dailySalesChart.options}
                    listener={dailySalesChart.animation}
                  />
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Daily Sales</h4>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>
                    <span className={classes.successText}>
                      <ArrowUpward
                        className={classes.upArrowCardCategory}
                      />{" "}
                  55%
                </span>{" "}
                increase in today sales.
              </p>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter chart>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <AccessTime /> updated 4 minutes ago
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
              <Card chart>
                <CardHeader color="warning">
                  <ChartistGraph
                    className="ct-chart"
                    data={emailsSubscriptionChart.data}
                    type="Bar"
                    options={emailsSubscriptionChart.options}
                    responsiveOptions={
                      emailsSubscriptionChart.responsiveOptions
                    }
                    listener={emailsSubscriptionChart.animation}
                  />
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Email Subscriptions</h4>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>
                    Last Campaign Performance
              </p>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter chart>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <AccessTime /> campaign sent 2 days ago
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
              <Card chart>
                <CardHeader color="danger">
                  <ChartistGraph
                    className="ct-chart"
                    data={completedTasksChart.data}
                    type="Line"
                    options={completedTasksChart.options}
                    listener={completedTasksChart.animation}
                  />
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Completed Tasks</h4>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategory}>
                    Last Campaign Performance
              </p>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter chart>
                  <div className={classes.stats}>
                    <AccessTime /> campaign sent 2 days ago
              </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>
          <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
              <CustomTabs
                title="Tasks:"
                headerColor="primary"
                tabs={[
                  {
                    tabName: "Bugs",
                    tabIcon: BugReport,
                    tabContent: (
                      <Tasks
                        checkedIndexes={[0, 3]}
                        tasksIndexes={[0, 1, 2, 3]}
                        tasks={bugs}
                      />
                    ),
                  },
                  {
                    tabName: "Website",
                    tabIcon: Code,
                    tabContent: (
                      <Tasks
                        checkedIndexes={[0]}
                        tasksIndexes={[0, 1]}
                        tasks={website}
                      />
                    ),
                  },
                  {
                    tabName: "Server",
                    tabIcon: Cloud,
                    tabContent: (
                      <Tasks
                        checkedIndexes={[1]}
                        tasksIndexes={[0, 1, 2]}
                        tasks={server}
                      />
                    ),
                  },
                ]}
              />
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader color="warning">
                  <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>
                    Employees Stats
              </h4>
                  <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                    New employees on 15th September, 2016
              </p>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Table
                    tableHeaderColor="warning"
                    tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                    tableData={[
                      ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                      ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                      ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                      ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                    ]}
                  />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>

        </div>
      </Grow>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling a while, I moved from React-chartlist to react-chartjs-2 which is wrapper of chartjs for charts being displayed